# How to reset Chrome dev tools CSS styles filter?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When clicking an HTML element in the Chrome dev tools and then selecting a CSS filter in the right bottom corner `Filter`, how can I reset this filter?

Please see my image below: I have selected the filter `border-bottom-color` and the left CSS part is highlighted yellow. Now when selecting another HTML element from the DOM, the element's styles are no more displayed, however this filter stays active and cannot be removed.

[image]

Comment: Element styles are showing, on any of your selected filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove from the filter border-bottom-color and then select the other html element.
[image]